# What governs Treasury funds out?

Tags: ink, pallet-treasury

My question is: What governs access to treasury funds? I’m assuming it requires an ink contract that governs who is able to invoke funds transfers out of the treasury and which conditions apply.

Is that accurate or are there other ways to grant access to treasury funds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comes from the [ApproveOrigin](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/69079b58579ea36812c4a375a118f27aac0fb281/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L150). In Polkadot, this is [configured to](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.18/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L793L796) 3/5 of the Council.

Comment: duh - awesome man thanks for the tip!